# Policy that allow program to access specific folder

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

can someone suggest hwat is the policy that I have to enable/configure to allor some program to access specific Folders.

As example my application get configuration file located in othe folder

Thank in advance.
Best Regards

Alpe

Answer (score 0):

**I have 2 links For you**

Visit https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/

Visit https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.06.srp.aspx